# Converting iOS5 app to ARC

Tags: xcode, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I am integrating some third party code into my app, and at the same time, trying to convert the app to ARC.

I'm attaching a screen shot to show the only two errors. If this is obvious to someone how to recode this section, I would be most grateful.

[image]

I have one more pita to solve. What's the most pragmatic way to solve this one:

```
value =  (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                             (CFStringRef)value,
                                                                                             CFSTR(" "),
                                                                                             kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

This gives this error:

"Cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') requires a bridged cast"

Thanks again.. I will lose this code asap...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `-performSelector:` anyway. Use `objc_msgSend(target, selector, ...)` instead.
If you call `-respondsToSelector:` you can just use `[vc setDelegate:self.delegate]` after the if-statement. The same is true for the first line. Replace it with:

```
UIViewController *vc = [vcClass alloc]; // vc = [[vcClass alloc] initWithSomething:[specifier file] ...]; if the initSelector is known at compile time
```

If the initSelector is dynamically generated:

```
objc_msgSend(vc, initSelector, [specifier file], ...);
```

Hope this helps.

**Update: Answer to the second question**

If you transfer CF objects to Objective-C objects, ARC needs to know how the memory management is handled. You have to insert `__bridge`, `__bridge_retained` or `__bridge_transfer` before the cast:

```
NSString *value;
value = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)value, CFSTR(" "), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

You use `__bridge` if you only want to cast between CF and Objective-C, `__bridge_retained` if it's a retained value and you handle that later using CFRelease and `__bridge_transfer` if you want to transfer the object from CF to Objective-C or vice-versa.

Comment: Please note I have added one other issue to the original post.

Comment: I wish I could add another point.. Your solution to the second issue was perfect as well.. Thank you again..

Answer (score 1):

You should use normal objc messaging, rather than `performSelector:` all over the place like that.

As well, you should:

- set `vc` to the result of the initializer.
- not need to message `release` (or call `[obj performSelector:@selector(release)];`) in an ARC program - the compiler will handle that for you.

One final underlying problem is that the initializer should not use a selector like that. If you really need that form, consider using/passing a convenience constructor instead of an initialization selector.

Comment: @David DelMonte I ended up removing that bit (about destroying) because it could have been interpreted as harsh (I didn't know whether you or the third party wrote that), when it was really just a red flag. I liked Fabian's answer best too. Cheers =)

Comment: I think you  are right Justin, but thanks.. This is a third-party app that I'm plugging into my app for immediate convenience. I will test the functionality I need and rewrite that. I appreciate all answers..

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you'd ever use performSelector: is when the selector is dynamically generated, if you know what selector you are going to use, then you should use it, so performSelector:@selector(alloc) makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Thanks Psycho, I took out the  performSelector:@selector(alloc). At least the code works. Now  that I have the functionality, I plan to rewrite using my own methods.